# What is the health of Chess.SE's beta from SE's point of view?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Has there been any comment from SE on their view of the health of Chess.SE's beta, and what is required to exit beta?

---

### [Related current stats:](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7551/chess)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, the most recent and most direct comment on the site's health from someone at SE has been Grace Note's answer to an [earlier meta question](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/277/167) about whether the site could pass beta or should potentially merge with Board and Card Games. In short, her comments largely reflected the information from your graphic above: she indicated that the site overall was in her eyes quite healthy (to the point of recommending *against* a merger), but that indeed it would need to have **significantly greater question volume** in order to have a chance to graduate.

In response to that, there has also been some [recent meta discussion](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/289/167) about how question volume might be increased.

Comment: +1 Thanks, reviewed Grace's answer, and did a quick review of the recent meta discussion too. Possible that I am missing something, though the issue I see is that it appears neither Grace, nor the meta discussion address how to get people to ask more questions (or why they might not be asking questions); meaning all that appears to have resulted was an awareness of SE's opinion, and users talking about how they can post more questions; neither of which in my opinion long-term will fix the issue. If SE is supposed to be the expert, they need to provide more info on how to fix the issue.